# Is it possible to apply two transformations with different origins to one div?

Tags: css, 3d, transform

I've got a div that I would like to rotate about its y-axis (with perspective) then do another 3d rotation on it around a different origin and display the result. Is this possible? I've only been able to get transformation-origin working outside of a -transformation statement, so defining a new transformation just overrides the first one.

I've also tried nesting divs and doing one transformation on an inner div and doing another on an outer div, but the result is just the projection of the first transformation on to the plane of the second, it does not exists on its own plane, so looks completely wrong on the screen.

As far as I'm aware I can't use canvas with javascript, because those transformations don't have perspective.

This is sort of what I am trying to do:

```
-webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
-webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(-90deg);
-webkit-transform-origin: 200px 200px;
-webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(x deg) rotateZ(z deg);
```

Any ideas on how I can see the result of both of these transformations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the answer, use

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

in a wrapper div.

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503115/css3-curved-surface-3d-transform-perspective-help) question, and as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cwolves/mwxNK/2/) and explained [here](http://www.webkit.org/blog-files/3d-transforms/poster-circle.html) (from the answers to that question).

Comment: Nice easy answer if it weren't for the fact that IE11 doesn't support it.  Ana's answer should be the accepted answer as it provides the general method of using a translate.  She has also provided a workaround for the preserve-3d not working in another question.

Comment: Here's that workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20725192/css3-3d-cube-ie-transform-style-preserve-3d-workaround

Answer (score 2):

A solution that does not involve having a wrapper is to chain the two transforms with a `translate3d` between them. Any translate transform moves the `transform-origin` for all subsequent transforms - `translateX(tx)` moves it by `tx` along the x axis, `translateY(ty)` moves it by `ty` along the y axis, `translateZ(tz)` moves it by `tz` along the z axis and `translate3d(tx, ty, tz)` moves it by `tx` along the x axis, by `ty` along the y axis and by `tz` along the z axis.

So your `transform` would become:

```
transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(-90deg) 
           translate3d(200px, 200px, 0) 
           perspective(1000px) rotateX(x deg) rotateZ(z deg);
```