# CSS3 - 3D Cube- IE transform-style: preserve-3d workaround

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, 3d

After looking through IE10's [developer blog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/hh673529%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#the_ms_transform_style_property) I have found that they do not support the preserve-3d setting.

I found this cube originally made by Paul Hayes which is working with touch screens and quite popular.

Altough preserve-3d setting is a known issue, I couldn't achieved suggested work around because it seems there is no transform property in the parent to maually apply to the child elements.
Here is the link that I simplified so far: http://jsfiddle.net/cC4Py/1/

CSS:

```
.viewport {

    perspective: 800px;
    perspective-origin: 50% 200px;
    transform: scale(0.75,0.75);

    -webkit-perspective: 800;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 200px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.75,0.75);

    -moz-perspective: 800;
    -moz-perspective-origin: 50% 200px;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.75,0.75);


}

.cube {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;


    transition: transform 50ms linear;
     transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 50ms linear;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;


    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 50ms linear;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;

}


.cube > div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 360px;
    width: 360px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 1);
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: -webkit-transform 50ms linear;
}

.cube > div:first-child  {

transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);


    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
}

.cube > div:nth-child(2) {
transform:  translateZ(200px);

    -webkit-transform: translateZ(200px);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(200px);
}

.cube > div:nth-child(3) {
transform:  rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);

    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
    text-align: center;
}

.cube > div:nth-child(4) {
transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(200px);

    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(200px);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(200px);
}

.cube > div:nth-child(5) {
transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(200px);

    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
}

.cube > div:nth-child(5) p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.77em;
    margin: 40px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.cube > div:nth-child(6) {
transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotate(180deg) translateZ(200px);

    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotate(180deg) translateZ(200px);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotate(180deg) translateZ(200px);
}

object {
    opacity: 0.9;
}

object:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body class="experiment">
<div class="viewport">
    <section class="cube" style="transition: 500ms; -webkit-transition: 500ms;">
        <div>MELABA!</div>
        <div>
            <h2>3D cube</h2>
            <time>28th September 2010</time>
            <p>By Paul Hayes</p>
            <p>3D cube built using css, webkit-perspective and webkit-transform. Rotation via webkit-transition.</p>
            <p>Use arrow keys to navigate, or click and hold mouse. On touch screens, use one finger to rotate. Press ESC to reset.</p>
            <p><a href="http://www.paulrhayes.com/2010-09/3d-css-cube-ii-touch-gestures-click-and-drag/" target="_top">Read more »</a></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <object width="360" height="360"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/MY5PkidV1cM?fs=1&amp;hl=en_GB&amp;rel=0"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/MY5PkidV1cM?fs=1&amp;hl=en_GB&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="360" height="360">
            </object>
            </div>
        <div>
            <h2><a href="http://www.paulrhayes.com/2009-07/animated-css3-cube-interface-using-3d-transforms/" target="_top">Learn how to make a cube</a></h2>
            <time>17th July 2009</time>
            <p>By Paul Hayes</p>
            <p>“A 3D cube can be created solely in CSS, with all six faces.”</p>
            <p>Article: <a href="http://www.paulrhayes.com/2009-07/animated-css3-cube-interface-using-3d-transforms/" target="_top">Cube explanation</a></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>I design and build websites in Brighton</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <small>Nothing down here.</small>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://www.paulrhayes.com/experiments/cube-3d/js/experiment.js?13"></script>
</body>
```

I created copies of every property without -webkit- prefix. Am I doing anything wrong? What should I do next?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, dragging and interaction in general usually means JavaScript. Yes, there are CSS hacks and I've used and abused them myself, but in this case it would be absolutely insane not to use JS.

So that means that you need to chain all the transforms from the ancestors (that means the rotation of the cube itself and the perspective you'd normally set on the parent of the cube) onto the faces of the cube via JavaScript.

You can do this in a few ways. In this case, I've used the style property of the face element, but you can also insert the styles into a style element.

Anyway...

## [*demo*](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/bdvya)

Relevant **HTML**:

```
<div class='cube'>
  <div class='face'></div>
  <!-- five more faces -->
</div>
```

Relevant **CSS**:

*Since I'll be changing transform values via JS, I didn't bother setting them in the CSS.*

```
.cube, .cube * {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
}

.face {
  margin: -8em;
  width: 16em; height: 16em;
}
```

**JS**:

*The code below is quick and dirty and can be improved.*

```
var faces = document.querySelectorAll('.face'), 
    n = faces.length, 
    styles = [], 
    _style = getComputedStyle(faces[0]), 
    factor = 3, 
    side = parseInt(_style.width.split('px')[0], 10), 
    max_amount = factor*side, 
    unit = 360/max_amount,
    flag = false, 
    tmp, p = 'perspective(32em) ';

for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  tmp = ((i < 4) ? 'rotateY(' + i*90 + 'deg)' : 
                   'rotateX(' + Math.pow(-1, i)*90 + 'deg)') + 
    ' translateZ(' + side/2 + 'px)';
  
  faces[i].style.transform = p + tmp;
  faces[i].style['-webkit-transform'] = p + tmp;
  
  styles.push(tmp);
}

var drag = function(e) {
  var p1 = { 'x': e.clientX - p0.x, 'y': e.clientY - p0.y }, 
      angle = {'x': -p1.y*unit, 'y': p1.x*unit};
  
  for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    tmp = 'rotateX(' + angle.x + 'deg)' + 
      'rotateY(' + angle.y + 'deg)' + styles[i];
    
    faces[i].style.transform = p + tmp;
    faces[i].style['-webkit-transform'] = p + tmp;
  }
};

window.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  var t = e.target;
  
  if(t.classList.contains('face')){
    p0 = { 'x': e.clientX, 'y': e.clientY };
    flag = true;
        
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', drag, false);
  }
  else {
    flag = false;
  }
}, false);

window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  if(flag) {
    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      _style = faces[i].style;
      tmp = _style.transform || _style['-webkit-transform'];
      styles[i] = tmp.replace('perspective(32em) ', '');
    }
  }
  
  flag = false;
  
  window.removeEventListener('mousemove', drag, false);
}, false);
```

Comment: I am on mobile now. Although I didn't get the whole code, your explaination seems very reasonable. I'll let you know the result as soon as possible!

Comment: It is working awsome! I think this is the only working code on the net for IE. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One more thing, there is a problem while drawing the faces. It draws the final div to the very top. Try to set the gamma to 1 and drag. I couldn't managed it.

Comment: If you want the faces to be completely opaque, then also set `backface-visibility: hidden` on them. I've added it in a comment in the CSS in the actual demo.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake, I am sorry. I can't believe how I missed it. I think I didn't know hidden was working for that. That's why it didn't took my attention. Thnaks a lot again and again.

Comment: Hi again!
`for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    tmp = 'rotateX(' + -20 + 'deg)' + 
      'rotateY(' + angle.y + 'deg)' + styles[i];`
I don't need the X rotation. -20deg perspective is enough for me. But it modifies the axis on each e send. Also tried to give rotateX transform to cube but it doesn't affect the whole cube. What should I do to fix the X rotation to -20deg?

Comment: Not entirely sure I get what you mean. I suppose you want [**something like this**](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/FGApg)?

Comment: Yeah, actually it is very close to what I tried to mean. This is the for loop on your "/* current transform values */" region. `for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) { tmp = 'rotateX(-20deg)' + 'rotateY(' + angle.y + 'deg)' + styles[i];` Please, modify just this for loop on your original java like I wrote above. Now, move the mouse on horizontal axis. That look is exactly what I want! But whenever you click to the cube for the second time, it rotates X -20 degree once more, which is I don't need. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: You are awsome! Thanks ma'am.

Comment: nice cube, how to put a link in each side of the cube? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer using CSS @keyframes, and setting up animations that way, to using JS. JS tends to introduce jank and freeze up pages. CSS, especially in Firefox, but also in Chrome, is very fast and smooth for 3d vizualization and animation. IE has a problem by not including preserve-3d. Until it does, I won't worry about whether things look as intended in IE. Just try to make sure there's an acceptibly graceful degredation if you have to support IE.